# Need help understanding cache writing

Tags: c, caching, architecture

I'm working through *Computer Systems: A Programmer's Perspective* and I'm stuck on a problem set with a 2048 byte direct-mapped data cache with 32-byte blocks.

```
struct point_color {
    int c;
    int m;
    int y;
    int k;
};

struct point_color square[16][16];
int i, j;

/* Outer loop #1 */

for (i = 0; i < 16; i++){
    for (j = 0; j < 16; j++) {
        square[i][j].c = 0;
        square[i][j].m = 0;
        square[i][j].y = 1;
        square[i][j].k = 0;
    }
}

/* Outer loop #2 */

for (i = 0; i < 16; i++){
    for (j = 0; j < 16; j++) {
        square[j][i].c = 0;
        square[j][i].m = 0;
        square[j][i].y = 1;
        square[j][i].k = 0;
    }
}
```

I'm also given the specifications of:

- `sizeof(int) == 4`
- `square` begins at memory address 0.
- The cache is initially empty.
- The only memory addresses are to the entries of the array square. Variables `i` and `j` are stored in registers.

For each outer loop ran separately, I must find:

A. The total number of writes.

B. The total number of writes that miss in the cache.

C.  The miss rate.

---

For Loop #1, I think that:

A. Each line in the inner loop writes 2 structure points separately. So since there's 4 lines, that's 8 writes per inner loop. For the entire block of code, 16 * 16 * 8 = 2048.

B. There's 1 miss per inner loop. 16 * 16 * 1 = 256.

C. 256 / 2048 = 1 / 8 = 12.5%.

Regarding loop #2, I think that the total number of writes is the same, but the missed writes are 2 for the inner loop, due to the switched dimensions. I'm not sure how to word that more precisely though.

So is my understanding correct?

Comment: *Each line in the inner loop writes 2 structure points separately* Huh? Why? I would say these are 4 writes. Can you elaborate please?

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves Each i and j is written to the cache, right?

Comment: I would say that one miss brings in cache 32 bytes, that is two continous structures; thus the Loop#1 generates only 256/2 misses. Loop#2 is 256 since you're not accessing continous structs.